# Runtime of an if-statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sorting, data-structures, runtime, theory

Suppose there is an array A containing n elements, and a line of code that contains an if-statement with multiple conditions, for example:

```
for i = 2 to n
    if A[i] > m and A[i] - A[1] = EVEN
        then set m to A[i]
```

Is the runtime for the second line n-1, or is it 2*(n-1) since there are two conditions for the if-statement?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, when you're talking about runtime, you need some sort of "cost model" to talk about how much each operation "costs." It's actually pretty unusual to see a cost model that would go into the level of detail that you're going into here - usually, you'd just abstract away the details and say that the cost of performing all those tests is O(1) (some constant that doesn't depend on the size of the input) rather than counting at that precise of a level.

If you are going to count at that precise of a level, you might also want to factor in the cost of the array lookups, whether or not things short-circuit, the effect of branch prediction or misprediction on the runtime, etc... and that partially explains why it's so rare to see people actually talk about things at that level of detail.

Comment: I agree: usually we'd just say that the condition is O(1) per iteration. In addition to what you point out, in this particular case the number of times the second condition (i.e. `A[i] - A[1] = EVEN`) is checked depends on the result of the first condition and whether the language allows short-circuiting evaluation.